# C++ - WriteFile - Utf16LE

Tags: c++

What is the default byte order for lpwstr strings?

I'm writing data to a file in c++ using WriteFile() function.I guess it writes the data in utf-16BE.I need to write the data in utf-16le.How can I achieve it?

Googled for hours and I didn't find a solution.

Comment: Where do the strings come from? LPWSTR just tells you it's 16 bit unicode characters, not what they look like. If you dig into where you are getting the strings, that should tell you more about them. Also, you can check the strings for the Byte Order Mark, which (if present) will tell you what you want to know.

Comment: There have been some Windows releases that ran on big-endian machines but that's long gone history.  The odds that you get utf16-be from an LPWSTR ought to be rather small.  Don't make us guess at your code.

Comment: @HansPassant What releases? Even on MIPS it was LE.

Comment: NT 3.51 ran on PowerPC.  That didn't last long.

Comment: @HansPassant If http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPC is true, `Solaris and Windows NT for PowerPC also ran the processor in little-endian mode.`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an [LPWSTR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc230355.aspx) I'll say that you are under Windows (and its variants), so probably on an Intel/AMD machine, so it's already Little Endian. `LPWSTR` uses the endianness of the processor. Windows hasn't ever been ported to Big Endian (at least from what I know)

Note that there is at least an exception: the XBOX 360 is Big Endian.

Comment: If I assign lpwstr to some string say 'asdf' and if I write it to the file, the string is in the form 'a s d f '..So I thought it must be Utf16BE..If it is not UTF16BE,May I know why it is writing to file as 'a s d f '?

Comment: @Ravee Because it's LITTLE endian :-) Little part before, big part after. In Unicode 'A' is still 65 (0x41)... If you pad it with some zeroes... 0x0041, and so in little endian order: 0x41 0x00 . First the letter and then the \0.

Comment: Oh :) Why it appends \0 in the data? can I write to the file without that '\0'?

Comment: If you want UTF16, you need 16 bits, which means two bytes in all common processors. If you are looking to write the string as 8-bits per character, you will need do convert it to UTF8 or ASCII or something. Can you edit your question to explain what you are actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`WriteFile` makes no transformation or other change to your data. If you pass it a `LPWSTR` then it will write it in the byteorder it is stored in the `LPWSTR` - which is PROBABLY "little endian" on any machine running Windows (at least, all the times I've looked at a Windows "Unicode" string, it's 16-bits of Little Endian data).

Comment: If I assign lpwstr to some string say 'asdf' and if I write it to the file, the string is in the form 'a s d f '..So I thought it must be Utf16BE..If it is not UTF16BE,May I know why it is writing to file as 'a s d f '?

Comment: If you have `"asdf"` in a LPWSTR, it will contain the bytes `'a', '\0', 's', '\0'`, etc.., where `'\0'` is the high part, and `'a'` etc is the low part. So it's "little endian" (low part first). A big endian storage would have `'\0', 'a', '\0', 's' ...`

Comment: Ok..My bad..Now how to remove the '\0's present in the String?

Comment: If you want UTF16, you don't. Sounds like you don't really know what you are trying to do...

Comment: @Ravee By doing another question titled "How do I convert an LPWSTR to an UTF8/ASCII string in Windows", or better first seaching for it, because surely someone else already asked for it.

Comment: Is there any difference between utf-16le in java and c++? Because when I write in java by utf-16le encoding,I didnt get this '\0' character appending with other characters.

Comment: Then Java isn't writing out as UTF16LE. How are you reading the data?

Comment: I did some mistake while writing file in c++ in calculating size of wchar string..That caused the whole mess.Now its fixed.Thanks !